# Python script as a safe exe and maybe even a Windows Store App?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I have a Python script which I ran pyInstaller on to create a portable windows exe which runs on Windows 7,8, and 10 devices. I signed the exe with Certum Open Source code signature. The app works great but I am finding:

1. Windows Smartscreen warns users that I am an unknown developer and makes it too scary for people to run my app.
2. Norton quarentines my app.

These are not good hoops for my users to have to jump through. I'm wondering what I can do to immediately address these.

As a secondary goal I am hoping there might be a way to submit the script to the Windows store. I am guessing I might need to have an installer for it instead of have it run as a portable exe? Do I need to create an appx? If so, what would the entry point be for a Python script frozen by pyInstaller?

In case it isn't obvious, I'm not a Windows programmer so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: executables created by py2exe, pyinstaller... are sometimes seen like viruses. They're actually a python interpreter running your pyc files from a .zip. I'd suggest that you look into Cython to create real executables (from C compilation).

Answer (score 0):

[cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is probably what you want! (cross platform)

[Py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) it's for Mac.

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) works on Windows and Linux.

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) it only works on Windows.

Comment: How will cx-freeze help ensure that Norton and Windows Smartscreen will see my app as safe?

Comment: I personally haven't tried that for windows since I primarily use Mac. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

pyInstaller works on Mac. I use it for a project of mine.

For Mac you have to have an Apple developer account to sign an application. 3rd party certificate authorities like Certum are no longer accepted.

For Windows apparently they use some sort of reputation type system. So even after you sign an exe it has to be downloaded and run enough times before it stops throwing the error.

As for Windows Store... you have to develop an app using the Universal Windows Platform API for them to allow it on the store, so I don't think a python script would qualify even if it was packaged as an exe.